# CFNetwork Logging for an unknown error/issue

Tags: json, swift4, xcode9, cfnetwork

I have the following function in my application:

```
// MARK: - Download JSON from ToH webserver
    func downloadJSON(completed: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let url = URL(string: "http://tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil {
                do {
                    self.tohBonuses = try JSONDecoder().decode([jsonBonuses].self, from: data!)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        completed()
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("JSON Download Failed")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

In my console when that function is called I am getting the JSON Download Failed error. I don't see any other errors around it though. Some googling pointed me to CFNetwork Diagnostics. I have ran the app with this set to both 1 and 3, but nothing obvious stands out. In both cases I do see a

> Response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

in my console, and when logging is set to 3, I see raw data flowing, but it isn't the contents of my JSON (I assume it is downloading it as a binary file).

One thing I did notice when I had the logging set to 1 is this line:

> 2018-05-02 22:37:43.079258-0700 PhotoPillion[88117:42881245] CFNetwork
>   Diagnostics [1:69] 22:37:43.079 {
>            Did Finish: (null)
>                Loader:  {url = http://tourofhonor.com/BonusData.json, cs = 0x0} init to origin load: 0.060393s
>            total time: 0.747829s
>           total bytes: 547511

That seems to indicate that it downloaded 578K of data, which is the size of the JSON file on disk. So I'm not sure what exactly is going wrong.

I'm not exactly sure what the next step is here.

EDIT to add some additional details: Prior to my function above I have a `var tohBonuses = [jsonBonuses]()` in my code and then that jsonBonuses() is a reference to a jsonBonuses.swift file that looks like this:

```
import Foundation

struct jsonBonuses:Decodable {
    let bonusCode: String
    let category: String
    let name: String
    let value: Int
    let city: String
    let state: String
    let flavor: String
    let imageBase64: String
}
```

Comment: Your parsing has failed.

Comment: @Sulthan Is there something I can do to see what specifically isn't being parsed? I added some additional details to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are not parsing the data correctly. The JSON would be parsed with the following objects:

```
struct Bonus: Decodable {
    let bonusCode: String
    let category: String
    let name: String
    let value: Int
    let city: String
    let state: String
    let flavor: String
    let imageBase64: String
}

struct JsonData: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let version: String
    let bonuses: [Bonus]
}
```

and then

```
let parsedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonData.self, from: data!)
self.tohBonuses = parsedData.bonuses
```

What you are trying to do is to parse JSON:

```
{ name: ..., version: ..., bonuses: ... }
```

to a type `[Bonus]`.

And that cannot work.

Also, to answer the question about printing errors, you can do it simply:

```
do {
  ...
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

See [Error Handling in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow exactly. I think you are saying that my struct doesn't match the structure of the JSON file. I should fix that in my jsonBonuses.swift file, right? Also, I'm not sure where I am pointing to a type of `[Bonus]`. I don't see the word Bonus in any of the code above. Lastly, the line `let parsedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonData.self, from: data!)` should go into the jsonBonuses.swift file as well, or do I need insert that into my function somewhere?

Comment: @DJFriar I am sorry, I have renamed your `struct jsonBonuses` to `struct Bonus` because your name did not make sense. That probably made my answer confusing. I am saying that you are trying to parse a JSON dictionary to an array `[jsonBonuses].self`.

Comment: No problem, they are named that way because in earlier versions of the app I was using bonus and bonuses for other things. Now that I'm trying to use the JSON file, I'm using names that have JSON in it. I have corrected the struct in my jsonBonuses.swift file, but it still returns my error. Do I need to change anything in my `downloadJSON` function to fix the parsing, or do I need to add that `let parsedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(JsonData.self, from: data!)` in the jsonBonuses.swift file? (the downloadJSON func is in my BonusTableViewController.swift file (UITableViewController)